# Angularjs "parse:syntax" error message

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, jsp

As I new to AngularJS, I want to understand the error messages display in console. Below you can find my json object and other details.

In JSP page:

```
<body id="bodyID" ng-controller="ApplicationParameterController" >
    <div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">{{init(${displayInfo})}}</div>
    <toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000}"></toaster-container>
    <application-param></application-param>
</body>
```

My json object:

```
displayInfo = [{"id":34,"key":"a","value":"true","description":"a","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":35,"key":"summaryReportEmail","value":"test@gmail.com","description":"summaryReportEmail","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":36,"key":"b","value":"true","description":"b","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":1,"key":"T_AND_C_ON","value":"Y","description":"c","privilege":{"privilegeID":74,"privilegeCode":"enable_tnc"}},{"id":3,"key":"soapAddress","value":"http://test.com/test/test.asmx","description":"soapAddress","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":4,"key":"soapAddressAlter","value":"http://test.com/test/test.asmx","description":"soapAddressAlter","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":27,"key":"d","value":"d","description":"d ","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":28,"key":"sts.s3.bucket.name","value":"test01-sts-healix-xmls","description":"sts.s3.bucket.name","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":29,"key":"e","value":"e","description":"e","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":30,"key":"f","value":"f/g","description":"f","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":31,"key":"g","value":"7","description":"g","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":32,"key":"enableScheduler","value":"true","description":"enableScheduler","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}},{"id":33,"key":"sts.document.api","value":"http://www.test.com/as-da-api","description":"sts.document.api","privilege":{"privilegeID":77,"privilegeCode":"app_param_admin"}}]
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=null&p3=init(%5B%7B%22id%22%3A34%2C%22key%22%3A%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22%2C%22privilege%22%3A%7B%22privilegeID%22%3A77%2C%22privilegeCode%22%3A%22app_param_admin%22&p4=init(%5B%7B%22id%22%3A34%2C%22key%22%3A%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22%2C%22privilege%22%3A%7B%22privilegeID%22%3A77%2C%22privilegeCode%22%3A%22app_param_admin%22 G/<@https://localhost:8443/travelinsurance-aggregator/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:6:457
```

My init method is:

```
$scope.init = function(displayInfo) {
                if ($scope.displayInformation == null || $scope.displayInformation == 'undefined') {
                    $scope.displayInformation = angular.fromJson(displayInfo);
                    $scope.applicationParameters = $scope.displayInformation;
                }
            };
```

When I try [json formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) it is showing there is no syntax error, but in error message its showing there is a syntax error. And I went through some site but I couldnt find the error solution.

- [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135255/how-to-understand-the-console-error-messages-in-angular-js-any-tools)
- [Angularjs link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax)

Can anyone help to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your controller method init() too please?

Comment: @rrd I have added the init method

Comment: Just check what happens after `{{init(${displayInfo})}}` is rendered by server-side script. The problem is very obvious.

Comment: @dfsq Its not calling init method.

Comment: Of course it's not going to call `init`. Because parser can't parse template. Because `{{init(${displayInfo})}}` is not correct. You need to properly encode data if you render it like this. Again, check rendered HTML and see that happens there - then you will see that JSON is not correct.

Comment: You can use like  ng-init="init()" and then inside that you can update your variable and showcase the inside expression

Comment: @dfsq How to check  rendered HTML. Sorry for this question. I very new to angularjs stuffs.

Comment: Open developer tools and check HTML that has been rendered.

Comment: @dfsq this is the error message description https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=null&p3=init(%5B%7B%22id%22:34,%22key%22:%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22,%22value%22:%22true%22,%22description%22:%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22,%22privilege%22:%7B%22privilegeID%22:77,%22privilegeCode%22:%22app_param_admin%22&p4=init(%5B%7B%22id%22:34,%22key%22:%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22,%22value%22:%22true%22,%22description%22:%22isAutoRenewalEnable%22,%22privilege%22:%7B%22privilegeID%22:77,%22privilegeCode%22:%22app_param_admin%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When I try to convert object of object to json string, I used below code:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String displayJson = null;
try {
    displayJson = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(applicationParametersForPrivilege);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson) I changed that to:

```
ObjectWriter jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String displayJson = null;
try {
    displayJson = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(applicationParametersForPrivilege);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now its working fine.